# C# From ObjectResult to string (or get value)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using a IActionResult (task) to upload a file and i refference that in my controller. What i want to get back is the file name.

Controller ->

```
        var imageLocation = await _imageHandler.UploadImage(image);
```

ImageHandler ->

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage(IFormFile file)
    {
        var result = await _imageWriter.UploadImage(file);

        return new ObjectResult(result);
    }
```

My value is stored in imageLocation, but i have no idea how to access it (i need the "Value" string so i can add it to DB).

[image]

I've tried searching for everything, but everyone is using a list. I only need a string here.
Hopefully you guys can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean you can't access it. You show the value there in the image. Cast the result to desired type and call property or just refactor the function to return the actual type

Comment: Its not a "i can't access it". Its more like...i dont know how to access it lol. First time i've used ObjectResult since i started learning C#. I tried many ways to refactor the function, but "IActionResult" is stopping me from returning strings and such.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can cast the result to the desired type and call property

*Controller*

```
var imageLocation = await _imageHandler.UploadImage(image);
var objectResult = imageLocation as ObjectResult;
var value = objectReult.Value;
```

or just refactor the `ImageHandler.UploadImage` function to return the actual type to avoid having to cast

```
public async Task<ObjectResult> UploadImage(IFormFile file) {
    var result = await _imageWriter.UploadImage(file);
    return new ObjectResult(result);
}
```

and get the value as expected in controller

```
var imageLocation = await _imageHandler.UploadImage(image);
var value = imageLocation.Value;
```

Better yet, have the function just return the desired value

```
public Task<string> UploadImage(IFormFile file) {
    return _imageWriter.UploadImage(file);
}
```

that way you get what is expected when calling the function in the controller.

```
string imageLocation = await _imageHandler.UploadImage(image);
```

Comment: Tried your 2nd suggestion first (refactoring with ObjectResult) and then i saw your edit. Both of those methods work. I'll go with the last one since it might be better. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just came across a `Result.Value` from FluentValidation Errors:

```
ObjectResult? result = (await controller.CreateSomething(InvalidDTO)) as ObjectResult;
List<FluentValidation.Results.ValidationFailure> value = (List<FluentValidation.Results.ValidationFailure>)result.Value;
```